# C PROGRAMMING CODEVISION AVR

Tags: c, avr, avr-gcc, codevisionavr

i cant understand some lines of this code please describe me what theise code do:
 this code is witten in atmelstudio and is a sample code of AVR443 application note of ATMEL

```
unsigned char *pTemp;
fastTemp.word = ((PIN_HALL & hallMask)>>1);
pTemp = pDrvPattern + fastTemp.word;
PORT_MC = *(pTemp);
```

as *pDrvPattern is defined as follow:

```
__regvar __no_init unsigned char *pDrvPattern 

pDrvPattern = drvPatternsCW;
unsigned char drvPatternsCW[] = {
0,    //Stop
// MC_PORT drive config
PDP2_CW, //Phase2
PDP6_CW, //Phase6
PDP1_CW, //Phase1
PDP4_CW, //Phase4
PDP3_CW, //Phase3
PDP5_CW,  //Phase5
// Configuration of Output Compare operation for timer 0
COM0P2_CW, //Phase2
COM0P6_CW, //Phase6
COM0P1_CW, //Phase1
COM0P4_CW, //Phase4
COM0P3_CW, //Phase3
COM0P5_CW,  //Phase5
// Configuration of Output Compare operation for timer 2
   COM2P2_CW, //Phase2
COM2P6_CW, //Phase6
COM2P1_CW, //Phase1
COM2P4_CW, //Phase4
COM2P3_CW, //Phase3
COM2P5_CW  //Phase5
};
__regvar __no_init union _fastTemp{
unsigned int word;
struct{
unsigned char LByte;
unsigned char HByte;  //Hbyte = Zero
};
} fastTemp @12;
#define PDP1_CW  ((0<<UL)|(0<<VL)|(1<<WL)|(0<<UH)|(1<<VH)|(0<<WH))
#define PDP2_CW  ((0<<UL)|(0<<VL)|(1<<WL)|(1<<UH)|(0<<VH)|(0<<WH))
#define PDP3_CW  ((0<<UL)|(1<<VL)|(0<<WL)|(1<<UH)|(0<<VH)|(0<<WH))
#define PDP4_CW  ((0<<UL)|(1<<VL)|(0<<WL)|(0<<UH)|(0<<VH)|(1<<WH))
#define PDP5_CW  ((1<<UL)|(0<<VL)|(0<<WL)|(0<<UH)|(0<<VH)|(1<<WH))
#define PDP6_CW  ((1<<UL)|(0<<VL)|(0<<WL)|(0<<UH)|(1<<VH)|(0<<WH))
#define HALL1 PB1
#define HALL2 PB2
#define HALL3 PB3
#define HALL_MASK  ((1<<HALL1)|(1<<HALL2)|(1<<HALL3))
#define PORT_MC PORTD
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: And your question is now? Which parts of the code you don't understand in particular?

Comment: what theise 2 code lines do exactly a poiner is added to int ??

Comment: pTemp = pDrvPattern + fastTemp.word;
    PORT_MC = *(pTemp);

Comment: Pointers added to an `int` (or vice versa) apply pointer artithmetic.

Comment: but value of pointer is an array ,,what does it do exactly..

Comment: _"what does it do exactly"_ It probably moves to the next array entry and assigns a value to it.

Comment: thank you all you you helped me.."""" pointer arithmatick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have is pulling a data field from a memory buffer. Rather than defining a structure with meaningful fields, the code created a character array, `drvPatternsCW[]`, and then created a pointer to that array with `pDrvPattern`. Setting `pTemp` to `pDrvPattern + fastTemp.word` is the equivalent of `pTemp = &pDrvPattern[fastTemp.word]`. `PORT_MC = *(pTemp);` ends up being the same as `PORT_MC = pDrvPattern[fastTemp.word]`.

Comment: thanks a lot you helped me to understand fully thanks a lot